# Getting error 4.4.5 Too many connections from your host when using mailkit

Tags: mailkit

Getting the error message below randomly when using MailKit to send mails.

> 4.4.5 Too many connections from your host.

I have the client object within a using block. Still seeing this error.

```
try
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    { 
        //send mail
    }
} catch() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to call the `Disconnect(true)` or `DisconnectAsync(true)` methods before the end of the `using` block.

While the `Dispose()` method *does* disconnect the socket, it does not send the QUIT command to the server, because it is bad practice for `Dispose()` to block. This means that the server still thinks that the connection is alive until their connection times out.